# Defining Eq instance on Fix f for functor f with Data.Functor.Foldable

Tags: haskell

I have the following functor:

```
import Data.Functor.Foldable

data ExprF a
    = ENum  Integer
    | EBool Bool
    | EVar  Var
    | EOp   Op [a]
    | EIf   a a a
    | ELam  Var a
    | EApp  a a
    | ERec  Var a
    | EZero            
    | ESuc a            
    | ECase a a Var a   
    deriving (Functor)

type Expr = Fix ExprF
```

and I would like to have an `Eq` instance defined for `Expr`. However, if I add `Eq` in the `deriving` clause, this doesn't seem to be enough somehow. And if I attempt to manually define an
`Eq` instance I get an overlapping error:

```
 • Overlapping instances for Eq Expr
        arising from a use of ‘GHC.Classes.$dm/=’
      Matching instances:
        instance [safe] Data.Functor.Classes.Eq1 f => Eq (Fix f)
          -- Defined in ‘Data.Functor.Foldable’
```

Can anyone suggest a way round the problem?

Comment: `Fix ExprF` already has an `Eq` instance, provided by `Fix` itself. Mostly what you are missing is an `Eq1` instance for `ExprF`, which is what the `Eq` instance for `Fix ExprF` requires.

Comment: @chepner Thank you I will look into defining an instance for `Eq1`. I was naively hoping that adding `Eq` to the `deriving` clause would do the right thing.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that a derived instance would probably only do a strict structural comparison. It wouldn't, for example, evaluate `Fix (EOp Plus [Fix (ENum 2), Fix (Enum 2)]` as equal to `Fix (ENum 4)`. In general, determining if two `Expr` values are equal is undecidable.

Comment: @chepner I am only interested in syntactic equality at this stage (hopefully that *is* decidable :), so implemented `Eq1` as you suggested, it all works fine.  Thanks v much for your help !